# How to solve Bazaar error bzr: ERROR: unknown command "*****"?

Tags: application-development, configuration, launchpad, bazaar

I am following [this guide](http://packaging.ubuntu.com/html/getting-set-up.html#configure-bazaar) to configure `bazaar`, but I have encountered a small problem, it says to type in the command:

```
bzr launchpad-login subgenius
```

And to replace `launchpad-login` with your LaunchPad ID, but I have done that:

```
bzr ***** subgenius
```

And I still get the same error message:

```
bzr: ERROR: unknown command "*****"
```

So should I just forget about this? Or is it something which I should do, and if so, then how and what am I doing wrong? (I have replaced information that I do not wish to provide with `*****`.)

---

**OS Information:**

```
Description:    Ubuntu 14.10
Release:    14.10
```

**Package Information:**

```
bzr:
  Installed: 2.6.0+bzr6595-1ubuntu1
  Candidate: 2.6.0+bzr6595-1ubuntu1
  Version table:
 *** 2.6.0+bzr6595-1ubuntu1 0
        500 http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ utopic/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
```

Comment: Could you past the full command that is returning the specified output? I don't that it is sensitive information :)

Comment: @Lucio: Ok, I have done that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> To tell Bazaar who you are, simply run:
>
> ```
> $ bzr whoami "Bob Dobbs <subgenius@example.com>"  
> $ bzr launchpad-login subgenius
> ```
>
> whoami will tell Bazaar which name and email address it should use for your
>   commit messages. With launchpad-login you set your Launchpad ID. This way
>   code that you publish in Launchpad will be associated with you.
>
> Note: If you can not remember the ID, go to https://launchpad.net/~ and see
>   where it redirects you. The part after the “~” in the URL is your Launchpad ID.)

<sub>(passage quoted from the [guide](http://packaging.ubuntu.com/html/getting-set-up.html#configure-bazaar) you mentioned)</sub>

If you read through that passage again, you see that not `launchpad-login` has to be replaced, but `subgenius`, which is obviously the name of the person who wrote that guide.

The command is `bzr launchpad-login YOURLAUNCHPADNAME`.